# Check the properties of the eigenfunction corresponding to the distinct eigenvalues of an integral equation

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ be eigenvalues and $f_1 , f_2$ be the corresponding eigenfunctions for the homogeneous integral equation
\begin{align}
 \phi(x) - \lambda \int_0^1 (xt +2x^2) \phi(t) \mathrm{d}t = 0 
\end{align}

We are given that $\lambda_1 = -18 - 6 \sqrt{10} , \lambda_2 = -18 + 6 \sqrt{10}$.

Check: Which of the following properties are satisfied

- $\displaystyle\int_0^1 f_1(x)f_2(x) \mathrm{d}x  = 0$
- $\displaystyle \int_0^1 f_1(x)f_2(x) \mathrm{d}x = 1$